# Import error in pyzmq after updating libzmq

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I have an error when I attempt to update my ZeroMQ to the new version 3.2. This is the ouput that I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from zmq import core, devices
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from zmq.core import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/core/socket.so: undefined symbol: zmq_sendmsg
```

I really don't know what's going on. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I develop in Python.
I've already checked on Stack Overflow but I did not see anything. It worked well before but I started to have this error after installing pyzmq 2.2.0.1.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks
MAXA

Answer (score 2):

As I [replied to you](http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2012-December/019868.html) on the zeromq-dev list, you must rebuild pyzmq any time you do a major upgrade of libzmq.